# how keep a control in windows form's view if scroll happened?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

i have a `Form` and it have a very big `dataGridView`(please ignore the datagridview) and so many other things. my `Form` is maximized and i set `AutoScroll` `True` and there is a `Button` on top of the `Form` when i scroll down `Button` goes out of user's view. i wanted to be like **fix** **position** in `HTML` so i tried to use `VerticalScroll.Value` somehow for `Button.Location.Y` in `Form` **Scroll** **event** but it didn't go well because i even don't know how this value of `VerticalScroll` will be calculated and have it nothing to do with `Form.Height` or not and the max value(when scroll is at bottom of form) is changing when you **resize** the `Form`.
have anybody any suggestion or solution for this?

Comment: In the `Scroll` event, you can set the Button's `Location` to the same initial value (some flickering expected). Or add a Panel (as a container for the controls that do have to scroll) to the Form and AutoScroll the Panel. The Button is of course outside the Panel. Or use an overlay (yes, right, for just a Button...hmm). Other...

Comment: @Jimi using another panel with scroll is the semi-solution that i'm using it now but i meant i want to know about ```scroll.value``` in order to set Button's ```Location``` in the ```Scroll``` event.thanks anyway.

Comment: Setting the *Button's Location in the Scroll event* is the first suggestion. When the ScrollableControl raises the Scroll event, re-set the Button's location to the same initial value. This will cause the Button to maintain the same relative position (since it will be repositioned in the ScrollableControl's [DisplayRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.displayrectangle) area). The choice depends on what *effect* you actually want to achive.

Comment: @Jimi sorry but i don't understand what do you of ''same initial value'' . i used ```button.Location.Y = this.verticalscroll.value;``` but it's not working(buttons moves faster than scroll and after some scrolling down it goes out of form) .can you please code your suggestion for me .it helps to understand your ''same initial value'' suggestion . Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same `.Location` value assigned to the Button in the designer. E.g., if you set  `[Button].Location = 100,100` in the designer, each time the `Scroll` event is raised, you re-set this initial position: `[Button].Location = new Point(100,100)`. This will cause it to maintain its relative position.

Comment: @Jimi thanks it worked. i didn't even think about this , silly me.i didn't even know controls's location value changes when we scroll . it was very helpful.

Comment: Oh, well, this is always something you find out by trial and error :) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Jimi another thing , do you know how to prevent Form **auto scrolling** when i click on another control ? i think it's because that control getting focus . i searched but all of them was about a `panel` not `Form` . sorry for taking your time again.